# Dictionary lookup of loaded yaml via a string representation in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, yaml, lookup

So I am using ruamel to read a yaml file located in github and all goes well.  I can see it loaded correctly.  Now my scenario is that this load is in a function in a class that I am accessing.  Now this function has a string variable "entry" which is what I want to search for.  The goal is to search at varying depths and I know the locations so I am not hunting for it.

**Sample Yaml file:**

```yaml
description: temp_file
image: beta1
group: dev
depends:
- image: base
  basetag: 1.0.0
```

**Entry string variable passing in**

I want to keep this a string for the variable "entry" as if looking for a top level lookup using the .get will return my value just fine.  Its just if I want to gather something like like the value of ["depends"][0]["image"], I cannot figure out how construct this so I can do the proper get.

```py
entry = "image"  # works fine
entry = '["depends"][0]["image"]'  #never works
gho.get_entry_from_ivpbuild_yml(repo, commit, entry)
```

**Code in Class**

```
# imports
from ruamel.yaml import YAML
yaml = YAML()
yaml.preserve_quotes = True

def get_entry_from_loaded_yml(self, repo, commit, entry, failflag=True):
    """
    :param repo: str (github repo)
    :param commit: str (sha of commit to view)
    :param entry: str (entry within yml you want to search for)
    :param failflag: bool (Determines if script fails or not if entry is not found within yaml)
    :return: str: (value of entry in yml you want to search for)
    """
    yml_file = "sample.yaml"
    try:
      logger.debug("opening yaml for commit:{}".format(commit))
      yml = self.gho.get_repo(repo).get_file_contents(yml_file, commit)
    except Exception as e:
      logger.error("Could not open yaml file:{} for repo:{} commit:{}:{}".format(yml_file, repo, commit, e))
      sys.exit(1)

    loaded = yaml.load(yml.decoded_content)

    if not loaded.get(entry, default=None):
      logger.error("Could not find value for {} in {}".format(entry, yml_file))
      if failflag:
        sys.exit(1)
      return None
```

Comment: I’m not entirely sure what you’re after, but if you want strings representing paths into a nested object, you probably want something more like `dpath` strings (`depends/0/image`) rather than strings representing the Python subscripting. There are libraries to do this (one called `dpath`, I think) on PyPI, although some of them work specifically with undecided JSON rather than decoded nested objects (because they’re designed to search huge JSON docs without needing to decode first), so look out for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already know, you can't pass something like the string `'["depends"][0]["image"]'` to `dict.get` and expect that to work. But there are a couple of options if you really need to specify a "path" to the object within a nested data structure like this.

---

The first is to do it explicitly, just passing a sequence of keys instead of a single key:

```
def get_entry_from_loaded_yml(self, repo, commit, entry_keys, failflag=True):
    # ...
    try:
        entry = loaded
        for key in entry_keys:
            entry = entry[key]
    except LookupError:
        logger.error("Could not find value for {} in {}".format(entry, yml_file))
        if failflag:
            sys.exit(1)
        return None
    else:
        return entry
```

And now, you can do this:

```
gho.get_entry_from_ivpbuild_yml(repo, commit, ('depends', 0, 'image'))
```

---

Alternatively, you can use a library that handles "key paths", in a format like `dpath` (which is essentially a simplified version of XPath) or ObjectiveC's KVC. There are multiple libraries on PyPI for doing this (although some work on undecoded JSON strings rather than decoded nested objects, to allow searching huge JSON texts efficiently; those obviously won't work for you… and I don't know of any that work on YAML instead of JSON, but they might exist). Then your code would look something like this:

```
def get_entry_from_loaded_yml(self, repo, commit, entry, failflag=True):
    # ...
    result = dpath_search(loaded, entry, default=None):
    if result is None:
        logger.error("Could not find value for {} in {}".format(entry, yml_file))
        if failflag:
            sys.exit(1)
        return None
    else:
        return result

# ...

gho.get_entry_from_ivpbuild_yml(repo, commit, 'depends/0/image')
```

This has the advantage that if you ever need to look up a (possibly nested) sequence of multiple values, it can be as simple as this:

```
for result in dpath_search(loaded, 'depends/*/image'):
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  The dpath was a perfect solution just changing it to:

    import dpath.utils
    entry = ('depends/*/image')
    result = dpath.util.values(loaded, entry) #Returns list
    return result[0]  #return first entry as result only has one entry in list

Simple and perfect solution for my problem.